# What are the classical adaptations of amphibians?

Tags: zoology

My question is about [amphibians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibian) in humid or underwater environments. What biological adaptations can found in them, further what purposes do they serve?

Comment: "Amphibian" literally means "living both in water and on land" (see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amphibian#Etymology))

Comment: Imagine asking "Why do fish prefer water over land?" Well... because they are adapted to water life but not land life. What kind of answer are you looking for exactly for amphibians? Do you want us to list adaptations of amphibians such as the eyes that are positionned to poke out of the water, the ears that don't let any water gets in, the skin who is thin and allow direct gazeous and water exchange or the webbed paws to move into water. Note that you will find many of these classical adaptations by just googling "amphibian adaptation".

Comment: @Remi.b: Indeed, if I were to try to answer this question from anything more than general knowledge, I'd simply copy parts of the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibian

Comment: @jamesqf Indeed. The OP changed the post without me noticing. I think the current post can basically be answered by my second comment. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Amphibian" means "living both in water and on land" (see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amphibian#Etymology)). Here is a small list of classic adaptations in amphibians:

- Eyes and nostril are positioned to poke out of the water while the rest of the body is immersed
- Ears don't let any water gets in
- Skin is very thin and allow direct gazeous and water exchange
- Paws are webbed to move into water
- Larvae of most amphibian species start their life in the water